# Javascript switch cases 1, case 2 and case 1 and 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 39:
            function1();
            break;          
        case 32:
            function2();
            break;
        case 39:
        case 32:
            function3();
            break;
    }
});
```

It works fine except for case 39: case 32:. 
It only works when case 39 and 32 are met at the same time. 
If case 39 is met first and then case 32 is met while case 39 is still met, only case 32 is run. 
What I'm trying to do is to run function3() when case 39: case 32: is met but not only when both are met at the same time. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: How can an integer be two different values at the same time?

Comment: May be he means when both keys pressed one after another? But it's should work, i think

Comment: FYI - use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode` - jQuery normalizes the key code across browsers into the `which` property

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, run the function when both keys are pressed one after another. But it only works when I press both keys at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch will simply match whichever case statement it encounters first.

In your code, `function3` can never execute, because when `e.keyCode` is 39, it matches the first statement, and when it's 32, it matches the second.  It will never reach the third section.

If you want `function3` to run when either condition is true:

```
switch(e.keyCode){
    case 39:
        function1();
        function3();
        break;          
    case 32:
        function2();
        function3();
        break;
}
```

If you want `function3` to *always* run, just place it afterwards:

```
switch(e.keyCode){
    case 39:
        function1();
        break;          
    case 32:
        function2();
        break;
}
function3();
```

Also, the idea that `e.keyCode` could be two different numbers simultaneously doesn't make any sense.  It's just a number variable. It can only hold a single number at a time.

In comments, you said you want to run code when two different keys are pressed one after another.  Well, then that's two different firings of this event.  You'll have to track some state.

```
var key39Pressed = false;
var key32Pressed = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
     switch(e.keyCode){
        case 39:
            if (key32Pressed)
                function3();
            else
                function1();
            key39Pressed = true;
            key32Pressed = false;
            break;          
        case 32:
            if (key39Pressed)
                function3();
            else
                function2();
            key32Pressed = true;
            key39Pressed = false;
            break;
        default:
            key32Pressed = false;
            key39Pressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to use 2 keys to do 3 different action. key 1 does action one and only action one, key 2 does action 2 and only action 2 and finally key 1 and 2 at the same time or one after another does action 3 and only action 3

Comment: @user1885099 the last code sample shows you the direction for making that work. use your magic mind and modify it to your needs :)

Comment: Updated the last sample to better match your first comment here.  However, you may want to adjust how some of the state variables get reset, depending on exactly the behavior you want.

Comment: Your example gave me the answer to my problem. Thank you for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an if statement for this with some additional state tracking.

```
var pressedKeys = {};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  pressedKeys[e.which] = true; //setting it up like this so I can use the "in" operator

  if(39 in pressedKeys) {
    if(32 in pressedKeys) {
      //both 39 and 32 are pressed
      function3();
    } else {
      //only 39 is pressed
      function1();
    }
  } else if(32 in pressedKeys) {
    //only 32 is pressed
    function2();
  }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  delete pressedKeys[e.which];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also ...

```
var t;    
switch(e.keyCode){
        case 39:
          function1();       
          t=1;
          setTimeout(function(){t=0},1000); 
        case 32:
            function2();
           if(t) { 
           function3();}
            break;
    }
```

So  if you press key before 1 second, function3 will call